# Получить всех юзеров из файла users.json, если файла нет, получить данные с сервиса

Tags: javascript, node.js

Нужна помощь с серверной частью. Имеется такое задание:
Создать следующее api
get /api/v1/users - получает всех юзеров из файла users.json, если его нет - получает данные с сервиса https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users, заполняет файл users.json полученными данными и возвращает эти данные пользователю.

И вся проблема в том, что я не понимаю, чего я не понимаю.
Пока что какие-то такие мысли:

```
readFile(`${__dirname}/test.json`, { encoding: "utf8" })  
      .then(text => {  
        const { users } = req.params  
        res.json({ users })  
      })  
      .catch(err => {  
        axios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')  
        .then((response) => response.data) 
          .then(data => {  
          /* тело ответа со стороннего сервера */  
          writeFile(`${__dirname}/test.json`, data, { encoding: "utf8" });
        res.json({ users })  
          }) 
      })
```

Comment: writeFile д.б. или Sync, или callback-used

Comment: @nörbörnën , увы, я видимо "особенный", ибо понятней не стало. И writeFile у меня прописан, но  vs на него тоже ругается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно проверить есть ли файл на диске. Затем, если файл есть на диске, его нужно вернуть вызовом `res.sendFile`. Если файла на диске нет, запросить у сервиса список пользователей, записать данные в файл и отдать результатом запроса.

При запросе списка пользователей у сервиса нет смысла разделять "получение и запись данных" и "оправку результатов запроса", всё пустим параллельно, используя stream-ы.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const { default: axios } = require('axios');

const app = express();

app.get('/api/v1/users', (req, res) => {
  const filepath = path.join(__dirname, 'users.json');
  fs.promises.access(filepath, fs.constants.R_OK)
    .then(() => res.sendFile(filepath))
    .catch(() => axios.get(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
      { responseType: 'stream' }
    ).then(({ data }) => {
      console.log('by_service');
      data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
      data.pipe(res);
    }))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('c', err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});

const EXPRESS_HOST = 'localhost';
const EXPRESS_PORT = 3000;
app.listen(EXPRESS_PORT, EXPRESS_HOST, () => console.log(`Server started on port http://${EXPRESS_HOST}:${EXPRESS_PORT}`));
```

И более современный вариант с async/await

```
app.get('/api/v1/users', async (req, res) => {
  const filepath = path.join(__dirname, 'users.json');

  try {
    await fs.promises.access(filepath, fs.constants.R_OK);
    return res.sendFile(filepath);
  } catch (err) { /* */ }

  const { data } = await axios.get(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    { responseType: 'stream' }
  );
  console.log('by_service');
  data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
  data.pipe(res);
});
```

И ещё вариант, который будет корректно работать в случае когда `users.json` отсутствует и несколько клиентов одновременно делают запрос к вашему api:

```
app.get('/api/v1/users', async (req, res) => {
  const filepath = path.join(__dirname, 'users.json');

  try {
    await fs.promises.access(filepath, fs.constants.R_OK);
    return res.sendFile(filepath);
  } catch (err) { /* */ }

  const { data } = await axios.get(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    { responseType: 'stream' }
  );

  // клиенту сразу отдаётся ответ сервиса
  data.pipe(res);

  // запись данных во временный файл и переименование после записи
  const tempfile = `${filepath}.${Math.random()}`;
  const stream = fs.createWriteStream(tempfile);
  stream.on('error', console.error);
  stream.on('finish', () => {
    try {
      fs.accessSync(filepath, fs.constants.R_OK);
    } catch (error) {
      fs.renameSync(tempfile, filepath);
    }
  });
  data.pipe(stream);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)